# Changing a component's property doesn't fire 'change' on other components

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have two components sideways in the same hierarchy (siblings). I am passing the model to both of them. I am changing the model data from a component, and want to catch all changes from the other one, but the components 'change' event fires only on the component which is used to change the value. It doesn't work in other components. How can I achieve this? I just want to communicate through the two components.

app/routes/applications.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            rejectFormData: {
                application_id: null,
                reject_reason: null,
                subject: '',
                body: ''
            }
        });
    }
});
```

app/templates/applications.hbs:

```
{{applications-list rejectFormData=model.rejectFormData}}
{{reject-dialog rejectFormData=model.rejectFormData}}
```

app/components/reject-dialog.js

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    change() {
        // this fires only when changed through this component
        // I want this to fire even when changed from other components
        alert('changed!');
    },
    actions: {
        rejectApplication(formData) {
            this.set('formData.application_id', 123);
        }
    }
});
```

app/components/applications-list.js

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    actions: {

        rejectApplication (application) {
            this.set('rejectFormData.application_id', application.Application.id);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Try doing `Ember.set(formData, 'application_id', 123)` instead, same for `applications-list`. Also I'm not aware of a `change()` hook in components, where did you read about it?

Answer (score -1):

You can't do what you want. Actions bubble up not in sibling way. You can change data in one and see data changes in other ones.

If you want to do a logic when a data is changed you need to use observer.

```
app/components/reject-dialog.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    changeObserver: Ember.observer('rejectFormData.application_id', function(){
  //do logic
}),
    change() {
        // this fires only when changed through this component
        // I want this to fire even when changed from other components
        alert('changed!');
    },
    actions: {
        rejectApplication(formData) {
            this.set('formData.application_id', 123);
        }
    }
});
```